# Crouton on Chromebook error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromebook

After I installed Crouton on my Chromebook (model number is Cb3-111), I restarted my Chromebook. When I tried to start Crouton, I got this:

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Wed Nov 2 23:41:41 PDT 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=9404eb5f-8bcd-064f-832b-9d054983e46c/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=9404eb5f-8bcd-064f-832b-9d054983e46c/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=3aa2c627e1ea0819661f88904efd9bdf16eee8f6 salt=1c2c61a2221dda7a1bbb5c96a01dae88b0ef65aa759f1fe00032d444117cf537" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=9404eb5f-8bcd-064f-832b-9d054983e46c add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Sat Nov 19 09:56:55 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

I have tried downgrading my Chromebook version, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take one more stab at this using a little different approach.

The 'xorg' xmethod may be throwing a wrench into things at the moment, due to either a CrOS update or something going awry in crouton itself.

We can add the 'xiwi' xmethod to your chroot(s) to see if that'll work for you. I use it almost exclusively even with 'kodi' and other video apps with no problem.

To add it use: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xiwi -n xenial -u`
Again, just substitute xenial (above) with your release.

Then you'll need to install the 'crouton integration' extension from the Chrome Webstore.

Installing the 'xiwi' target this way will make it the default xmethod but you can still use both 'xiwi' and 'xorg' by specifying command-line options.

Once the glitch with 'xorg' is fixed you may want to use it instead.

Then start your desktop in one or more of the following ways:

- launch desktop in a window (xiwi default): `sudo startxfce4`
- launch desktop fullscreen: `sudo startxfce4 -X xiwi-fullscreen`
- launch desktop in a browser tab: `sudo startxfce4 -X xiwi-tab`
- launch desktop in a separate screen: `sudo startxfce4 -X xorg`

You can, of course, substitute startxfce4 (above) with startlxde or any other desktop you've installed.

When launching in fullscreen you can use the keycombo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch between your chroot & CrOS.

Hope this helps,
DennyL

P.S. This mission, should you decide to accept it, will not cause your chroot(s) to self-destruct. :-)
       I would, however, like to know your results so please come back and let us know. I copied this from a post that helped me. It was a guy named DennyL and it worked.

Comment: Same as the original, i got The "No screen" error.